# In Firefox, modifying a range cloned from the selection clears the selection the first time

Tags: javascript, firefox

```
<script>
    var is_gecko = /gecko/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    var is_ie    = /MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent);

    function insertNodeAtSelStart()
    {
        if(is_gecko)
        {
            var S = window.getSelection();
            if(!S.isCollapsed)
            {
                var R = S.getRangeAt(0);
                var R1 = R.cloneRange();
                var NN = document.createElement("startMarker");
                R1.insertNode(NN);
                NN.parentNode.removeChild(NN);
            }
        }

        if(is_ie)
        {
            // IE-specific code
        }
    }
</script>

<div>
    <span>one two three</span>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Insert node at selection start" onclick="insertNodeAtSelStart();" />
```

The first time I click the button after loading the page and selecting some text, Firefox clears the selection. Subsequently, it does not. Is this a bug in my code or in Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox clears the selection when you disturb it by successfully inserting the Node inside its start point.

For me, a second click *sometimes* (depending on what range of text is selected) fails with a:

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount"  code: "1" nsresult: "0x80530001 (NS_ERROR_DOM_INDEX_SIZE_ERR)"  location: "..."]
```

on the insertNode call. Since the insertion is unsuccessful the selection is not cleared. Presumably this is what is happening for you — check your Error Console.

This failure does appear to be a Firefox bug. I can't quite track down the exact conditions that trigger it, but it is to do with what node boundaries are in the selection.

I can make your example always work (and clear the selection) by calling document.body.normalize() to return the whole span content to a single Text node, after it has been split by the insert/remove cycle.

Comment: Thank you. My opinion is that it should not clear the selection, and the fact that it does clear it the first time is a bug in Firefox. Off to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ then, I guess.

Comment: It's arguable whether the selection collapsing is a bug; certainly other applications do the same thing when a change is made to selected content. It should be possible to remember the old selection range and set it back once you've finished processing.

Comment: OK, I've managed to work out how to remember the old selection range and set it back afterwards, which is good enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you stumbled upon an ugly Gecko bug that keeps crawling back to life for too many years :(
And yes, the latest development build still presents this bug.

Anyway, if you don't want to wait for a fix from Mozilla, a simpler/faster workaround would be to collapse the range before inserting the new node.

For conformity, here's the (somehow simplified) sample used for testing your code:

```
<p id="para">select two or more letters, then </p>
<input id="butt" type="button" value="click me">
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (!window.getSelection)
    throw new Error("MSIE, you're not welcome!");

  var marker = document.createElement('span');
  marker.style.color = '#6C6';
  marker.appendChild(document.createTextNode('|'));

  function insertNodeAtSelStart() {
    // window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).insertNode(marker.cloneNode(true));
    var r = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var n = marker.cloneNode(true);
    r.collapse(true); // workaround for Gecko :(
    r.insertNode(n);  // Gecko sometimes(?!) fails with NS_ERROR_DOM_INDEX_SIZE_ERR
  }
  document.getElementById('butt').onclick = insertNodeAtSelStart;
</script>
```

OT, that's not "is _ gecko", "is _ not _ ie" would be more appropriate, as this code should run as expected on every browser except MSIE ;-)